# variable comparision in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file in which I need to call two other batches depending on a condition. And the condition is, I have two variables in a text file (Two strings. For Eg:2016JanFcst and 2016FebFcst). Now I have t0 read these two variables from my batch and check if these two are equal.
And if these two variables are equal I have to call one batch else the other one. Can anyone let me know how this can be achieved?

Below is what I have tried

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
set var1=A
set var2=B
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (D:Testing.txt) do (
SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
set var!vidx!=%%A
)
ECHO !var1!
ECHO !var2!
IF !var1! == !var2!
GOTO :Success
ELSE
GOTO :Failure
```

But it's giving me the error

> syntax of the command is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I think your if/else is off.

I got it to run with the following:

`IF !var1! == !var2! ( 
    GOTO :Success
) ELSE (
GOTO :Failure
)`

Here's where I looked: http://ss64.com/nt/if.html